# Restrict instance size on Google Cloud Platform Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to restrict the instance size on Google Cloud Compute?

For example, can I set limits saying a machine cannot be larger than 2 CPUs and 2Gb of memory. Given the IAM, it looks like I only have control if the user is allowed to start VMs via the *roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1* role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to restrict the maximum size of a Compute Engine instance.